# Why are the names of predicates in scheme in the form of questions?

Tags: scheme, naming-conventions

Racket is the first dialect of scheme I am learning, and I’m not that far in, however due to scheme’s minimal syntax, I believe it’s safe to assume that a question mark in variable names is not treated by the interpreter any differently than any other viable character.

With that run on sentence out of the way, why does scheme use the symbol “?” to denote a function that returns true or false (called a predicate)? For example, in racket, there is a built in function called `number?`.  `number?` returns true when applied to any number (1, 5, -5, 2.7, etc), and false otherwise.  I believe that `number?` is short for something along the lines of `is_the_following_argument_a_number?`.  Assuming that is true, the expression `(number? 5)` translates into `(is_the_following_argument_a_number? 5)`.

In english (the language this variable was written in), the predicate of “is the following argument a number?” can be found by first translating the question into its statement form by moving the verb: “the following argument is a number”, and then extracting the predicate: “is a number”.  Now, I’m not the best at speaking languages as I am at programming languages, but I believe that is correct.  Also, sorry if this is turning into an english question more than a scheme question.

What I am having trouble understanding is the fact that if the lisp community calls `number?` a predicate, why is the variable name not a predicate in english (I say that the variable **name** isn’t a predicate in english, not the **type of function** it is in scheme isn’t a predicate)  I found what I thought the predicate of what I thought `number?` translated into, as being “is a number”, not the entire question “is the following argument a number?”, just the predicate.  So, why does the lisp community choose to name predicates in scheme as questions in english?  I believe that this is because the community mistakes the values of statements (true or false) for the answers to yes/no questions (yes or no (obviously)).  Am I wrong to think this?

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted this good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A predicate in computer science doesn't have anything to do with a predicate in language grammar. They both derive from having to do with thruth but otherwise they are unrelated concepts. A predicate in Scheme is a procedure that checks if something is true or not and in reality it can have any name. However since we can code information in the name it should contain to the point what it is about, which can be any word or even sentence delimited by hyphens, ending with question mark to indicate that it is indeed a predicate procedure. Both the name in the definition and the usage will stand out to the reader so that they know it without looking at the documentation or the implementation.

[Scheme predicates](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.5) in the very [first Scheme report](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-349.pdf) and [the second](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-452.pdf) looked like [Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Front/index.htm) and the predicates in Scheme followed the same naming convention as Common Lisp has today. Old procedures that were in [LISP 1.5](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/book/LISP%201.5%20Programmers%20Manual.pdf) has the same name without the common p-ending while new introduced ones had it, like `procp` (called `procedure?` today). The reason for this is that Scheme run under MacLisp and borrowed all the dull stuff from it while it was lexical closures that were the magic of Scheme. Actually, it looked a lot looked like Common Lisp.

In the RRRS or R2RS they made all predicated end with ? and it worked with `eq?` and friends but the arithmetic predicates that used symbols, like `<?`, `=?`, `<=?`, etc,  was not a success and were removed in the [R3RS](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r3rs_toc.html).

In a conditional we call the parts predicate, consequence and alternative:

```
(if (< a 0) ; predicate 
    (- a)   ; consequent 
    a)      ; alternative
```

Here a predicate is just an expression that either turns true or false. Actually all Scheme values are allowed and only `#f` is false. A predicate procedure is a procedure that always either returns `#t` or `#f` and it is as you are writing that `number?` check whether the argument is a number and `string=?` checks whether two arguments are strings that look the same. The pattern is very good and you can imagine what it does just by looking at the name being used while keeping the procedure names short. In speech we often do the same, like saying "coffee?" and getting either positive or negative response. It works most of the times and some times people need to spell it out that they are offering them a hot beverage whose name is coffee. In coding that means looking in the documentation or definition of a procedure.

There are other naming conventions in Scheme.

`foo->bar` is a procedure that takes an argument that is a `foo` type and it returns it as a `bar` type. `number->string` takes a number and makes a string representation of it. `(number->string 5)  ;  ==> "5"`

`foo!` may change the objects you pass it in order to do the job slightly faster than if it was named `foo`. `set!` and `set-car!` are examples.

`*variable*` are from CL but in Scheme you can be sure it is a global variable.

`CONSTANT`, `+CONSTANT+`, `+constant+` are common naming for variables that are considered to be constants.

`form*` does something similar to what `form` does, but not quite. Special form `let*` does something similar to `let` but it binds one variable at a time.

The code works whether you follow these or not, but you are making it easier to read by using this convention and when you try to make a somparison procedure `foo=?` is just as easy to understand as `are-these-two-foo-things-equal` and `foo?` is just as easy as `argument-is-a-foo`.

Note that other programming languages also does this. In Java one write `isFoo` and `equals` so it's not spelled out there either.

Comment: So it doesn't have anything to do with English?  Just abbreviation and typing less?

Comment: @Vityou English didn't invent ambiguous and prompt questions as they exist in all the languages I know of. The standard procedures and the predicates are well known and they do have enough context so that once you understand what the word means eg. `number` you can understand `number?`. When that said user predicates might be more ambiguous and sometimes it needs more more words. eg. `valid?` might be ok if your program works with one type of data and has only one obvious validation predicate while `list-valid?` and `element-valid?` in another since they both check validity.

Comment: What I'm asking in my first comment is that if your saying people can "figure it out", even though a predicate function's name isn't a predicate in English, does it not have anything to to with English even though the variable name `number` is an English word.

Comment: @Vityou A predicate in computer science doesn't have anything to do with a predicate in language grammar. Both has to do with something about thuth but they are otherwise unrelated. If you make a predicate procedure that checks if a number is square and name it `square?` the name when you are using it will indicate it is a predicate, as in a special class of procedure that returns true/false, helping the reader understand what function it serves or even what it does by just looking at the procedure name. In CL they add a `p` (for predicate), like in `oddp`, and it does the job too.

Comment: Why do you write the name of the function in English, but don't recognize any other rules of English.  From what your saying, any combination of characters with a question mark at the end should be a predicate, regardless of whether or not you know what either the string of characters or the question mark mean as long as the interpreter does.  Programs should be written so that humans can read them.  And actually predicates in English are the exact same as predicates in computer science.  Both are expressions that can be labeled as true or false.  That's why they both use the same name.

Comment: @Vityou Why can is ask someone in english if they would like tea just by saying tea with an upward tone and without the use of any predicates? Why can I do it without forcing the rules of making a whole complete sentence? Why would anyone want to communicate with few words when they can make long sentences? If you like, you can. You can also make very long procedure names and they don't need to conform to anything so choice is yours to follow convention or not.  Classifications of words in a sentence and a predicate in CS (branch predication) are not the same.

Comment: To answer your first question the reason that you can ask someone "tea?" is that there is a human interpreting whether someone asked them if they would like tea or whether tea was the answer of a question they asked.  In either case, the predicate would be substituted into the question upon interpretation and the human would say yes or no.  This can also be interpreted as if you want tea, answer yes, otherwise, answer no.  You want tea is the predicate.  The difference is that there is no "yes or no" in computer science, however similar it seems to "true or false".

Comment: @Vityou The naming conventions and even choice of name for procedure are not for the computers but for humans to make sense of code that has been written. The choice of name and convention is to help understand what it's for an thus work the same way as communications between humans. Sometimes the two humans are yourself at different ages.

Comment: What I am saying is that scheme **chooses** to do something other than "work the same way as communications between humans" by using questions as predicates when scheme could use predicates as predicates.  I get that it is a naming convention, but I don't get why books like HTDP say that programming is a tool to "force a creator to articulate his or her thoughts in proper and precise English" if this is true.  From what I see here, the naming conventions are a flat contradiction to that statement.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a programming convention. Predicates - meaning: those procedures that return `true` or `false`, are defined with a name that ends in a question mark. Similarly, Procedures that have side effects (e.g., that mutate state) are defined with a name that ends in exclamation mark.